# How to get github repo notification using python script?

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I have to build a python script which will use to get the notification related to a github repo which contents pull notification, comments, merge to master status etc. After searching I got [PyGithub](http://pygithub.github.io/PyGithub/v1/introduction.html/%22PyGitHub%22) library. but did not get how to make a call and get response in python. Please suggest how to do this using PyGitHub library? Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Can you edit your post to add the script, as well as the error / unexpected behavior you encounter?

Comment: @ValentinLorentz : I have tried simple things, but actual problem is that I did not understand how to make call to notification API which is given in PyGithub documentation. Docs only provide the API name and response. Actually it did not content any example to try out. 
Following are the link for getting repo notification
[link] (http://pygithub.github.io/PyGithub/v1/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository)